# How to print in current terminal new logs arriving in a logfile?

Tags: command-line, systemd, services, logging, output

I can't find the answer to my question, and I don't know how to proceed...

I would like to print in my current terminal (possibly only for a specific user) new logs added to a logfile, without running any command. I would like to be informed of specific events without manually check into the logfile.

I would prefer to monitor the logfile instead of redirect service's output to both logfile and console. And if I could filter and display only desired logs, it would be perfect...

May you can help me achieving this ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to achieve this with a command like tail with the -f parameter piped into the less command.

With a particularly long and growing log, you can try this in the terminal.

```
    tail -200f agent-install.log | less
```

As new log messages flow into your log file, you can continue to see them.

You can use all the keyboard controls in less as you would in using less with a static file.You can use all the keyboard controls in less as you would in using less with a static file.

Control-C stops the whole command.